# How can I measure the number of indirect links between 2 websites?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like to measure how strong the relationship between two organisations is.
One idea is to take the urls of the web presence of those organizations and measure how many direct (if any) or indirect links (via intermediary sites) go from one presence to the other.
Both, the number of such parallel links could be an indicator as well as typical numbers of steps necessary to connect those sites (how many intermediary sites are necessary).
This could be done with a python script. I guess requests, lxml, BeautifulSoup would be useful for that purpose but most likely such programs already exist?
Can you please point me in the right direction?
Do you have alternative suggestions?
Dou you think this could even work?

Thanks very much in advance.

I have added this rough sketch (sorry) to illustrate what i mean.

[image: links between 2 sites]

Comment: You'll have to recursively scan every site that is linked, to get more links, and so on. You'll end up scanning the whole internet pretty soon, unless you want to stop after a certain depth

Comment: You could look at this list: https://www.octoparse.com/blog/top-20-web-crawling-tools-for-extracting-web-data ; or search Google for "Web Crawler"s; as "Ofer Sadan" mentioned, you will need to, essentially, scan a huge part of the Internet.

Comment: If you want to implement this manually, you will probably need a queue to store the links that will need to be processed later: every time you find a link inside the current page, it should be added to the end of the queue, unless it has been processed before; you will also need some graph-like structure to store which sites link to what. Depending on how far you want to dig, you may store those on memory, or on a database.

Answer (score 0):

The following stackoverflow pages are related:

[Find shortest path between two webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902143/find-shortest-path-between-two-webpages)

[Shortest path algorithm for URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900637/shortest-path-algorithm-for-urls)

From a matlab perspective:

https://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2021/04/01/shortest-path-between-two-web-pages/#like

And finally this project (written in Rust) seems to do what I was looking for:

https://rustrepo.com/repo/qwercik-explore-rust-miscellaneous

I have compiled it and started testing/evaluating.